# serializer is not define, can't make Nested relationships

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have try this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships
but always show error "undangan = InvitationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
NameError: name 'InvitationSerializer' is not defined"

```
class TypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      undangan = InvitationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

      class Meta:
         model = Type
         fields = [
             'id',
             'typeName',
             'info',
             'created',
             'undangan',
         ]
```

and this is the serialaizer I want to call

```
class InvitationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

     class Meta:
         model = Invitation
         fields = [
             'invitee',
             'invitationType',
             'owner',
             'created',
             'fkinvitationWedding'
         ]
```

[terminal when I run project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mogdL.png)

Comment: Try to change the order of the serializers. Define fisrt the `InvitationSerializer` serializer and then the `TypeSerializer` one